# ReactJs | Can not read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have app.js as the parent and uploadlist.js as the child. I am passing "userid" which is defined in app.js to uploadlist.js. This is my try:

app.js :

```
export default class App extends Component {

  state = {

    userrole : '',
    custid   : ''

  };

componentDidMount() {

  if(localStorage.login)
  {
    const currentuser     = JSON.parse(atob(localStorage.login.split(".")[1])); 
    this.setState( {userrole: currentuser.role });
    this.setState( {custid: currentuser.id });
    
  }

}

render() {

if(this.state.userrole === "Customer"){
  const userid=this.state.custid;
  console.log(userid); //This properly returns the userid in console.
return (
//some code
<Route path="/Uploadlist" render={props => <UploadList userid={props.match.params.userid} />}/>
```

uploadlist.js:

```
export default function Uploadlist() {
const userid = this.props.userid;
    console.log(userid);
```

This returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" error.
How can I solve this?

Comment: console log the props.match.params see if has the userid

Comment: @AmirHossein I tried `console.log(props.match.params)` in App.js. It returns "props is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

`Uploadlist` is a functional component. It doesn't have `this` - rather, its props will be in the first parameter passed to the function, in the shape of an object.

```
export default function Uploadlist({ userid }) {
  console.log(userid);
```

or use a class component to reference `this.props`

```
export default class Uploadlist() {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.userid);
```

Comment: I tried the first method as I want it as a functional component. But it returns 'undefined'. Why is that? @certainPerformance

Comment: If `<UploadList userid={props.match.params.userid}` and `export default function Uploadlist({ userid }) {` logs undefined for `userid`, then the prop you're passing is undefined - the problem is in the parent `app.js`, but there isn't enough code to see what the problem might be there - try some debugging in the parent component.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't still configure the issue in app.js  hence I updated the question with app.js code.  can you have a look in it?

Comment: the issue is because you don't send the userId to the upload list component `<UploadList custid={props.match.params.custid} /> `

Comment: @AmirHossein Sorry it is a mistake I have done when editing this question. I have `<UploadList custid={props.match.params.custid} />` in my app.js. But it doesn't working.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to pass props to the component rendered via `Route` use `render` prop instead of `component` .

Change your component as below

```
<Route path="/Uploadlist" render={props => <UploadList userid={props.match.params.userid} />}/>
```

Also you are trying to access `props.match.params.userid` you won't have the userId here because you are rendering this component for the path `/Uploadlist` . But if the `props.match` is from a parent component which renders this `Route` then to avoid name collision change the name of your props as

```
render={routeProps => <UploadList userid={props.match.params.userid} {...routeProps} />}
```

Now you can access the props in your component as

```
export default function Uploadlist({ userid }) {
  console.log(userid);
```

**Refer**

[Route Render Function](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func)

[Route component Prop](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component)

Answer (score 0):

UploadList is a functional component. Your route passes values top the component but when you defined UploadList, you did not accept any props as parameter.

It should be

```
function UploadList(props) {
.....
}
export default UploadList;
```

Or like @certainperformance answered, you could even use ES5 de-structuring to destructure the props parameter.

If you want to use 'this' use a class based component but that's a bit archaic and functional components are the best way to go for it these days

Comment: Hello. I had tried this way also. I got the above mentioned typeError  when using this method also.